# How to fix my C++ fighting game with Run-Time Check Error?

Tags: c++

I have been receiving an issue that I do not understand. The issue is:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'win' is being used without being initialized.

I am struggling to comprehend where my error is within the code. From what I understand the run time error comes from win not being initialized meaning it hasn't been used or set, however, it clearly is set in the fightScene() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "Character.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Blacksmith.h"

using namespace std;

void startup();
void createCharacter();
void existCharacter();
void secondFighter();
void fightScene();
int fightMoves(int att, int sp, int num);
void roundWon();
void characterLost();
void use_bar();
void newlines();
void changeCase(string &convert);
void bSmith();

Character existingCharacter[4] = { Character("Shabu", 10, 10, 10, 0, "Empty"), Character("Calil", 15, 15, 15, 0, "Empty"), Character("Goltero", 20, 20, 20, 0, "Empty"), Character("Balrogg", 30, 30, 30, 0, "Empty") };
Character cCharacter[2] = { Character(), Character() };
Character cCharacterSave("Empty", 20, 0, 0, 100, "Empty");
Item bars(0, 0, 0);
int timesWon = 0;
int purposeIgnore = 0;
char repeat = 'y';

int main() {
    startup();
    while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y') {
        fightScene();
        if (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')
            secondFighter();
    }
    return 0;
}

void startup() {
    int playerChoice;
    cout << "**************************" << endl;
    cout << "*      Loading Game      *" << endl;
    cout << "**************************" << endl;
    cout << "Which Would You Prefer?" << endl;
    cout << "1: New Character..." << endl;
    cout << "2: Load Character..." << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Enter Selection: ";
        cin >> playerChoice;
    } while (playerChoice <= 0 || playerChoice >= 3);
    if (playerChoice == 1)
        createCharacter();
    else if (playerChoice == 2)
        existCharacter();
    return;
}

void createCharacter() {
    string Name;
    string inventory;
    int h, att, sp, gc;

    cout << "***************************" << endl;
    cout << "*   Creating New Player   *" << endl;
    cout << "***************************" << endl;
    cout << "What Shall We Call You?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Name Here: ";

    cin >> Name;
    changeCase(Name);

    cout << Name << ", let's set your stats!" << endl;
    cout << "Set your ATTACK between 1 - 10" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Enter Attack Here: ";
        cin >> att;
    } while (att <= 0 || att >= 11);

    cout << "Set your SPEED between 1 - 10" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Enter Speed Here: ";
        cin >> sp;
    } while (sp <= 0 || sp >= 11);

    h = 20;
    gc = 100;

    cout << "The HEALTH stat wil increase over time, but as of now, " << Name << ", has " << h << " health!" << endl;
    cout << Name << " you have been granted " << gc << " gold!" << endl;

    cCharacter[0] = Character(Name, h, att, sp, gc, inventory);
    cin.ignore();
    return;
}

void existCharacter() {
    string characterChoice;

    cout << "***********************" << endl;
    cout << "*   Existing Player   *" << endl;
    cout << "***********************" << endl;

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i >= 0 && i <= 3; i++, j++) {
        cout << j << ": " << existingCharacter[i].getName();
        cout << "\t" << "Health: " << existingCharacter[i].getHealth();
        cout << "\t" << "Attack: " << existingCharacter[i].getAttack();
        cout << "\t" << "Speed: " << existingCharacter[i].getSpeed();
    }

    cout << "Enter Selection: ";

    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, characterChoice);
    changeCase(characterChoice);

    if (characterChoice == "1" || characterChoice == "Shabu") {
        cCharacter[0] = existingCharacter[0]; cCharacterSave.setHealth(existingCharacter[0].getHealth());
    }
    else if (characterChoice == "2" || characterChoice == "Calil") {
        cCharacter[0] = existingCharacter[1]; cCharacterSave.setHealth(existingCharacter[1].getHealth());
    }
    else if (characterChoice == "3" || characterChoice == "Goltero") {
        cCharacter[0] = existingCharacter[2]; cCharacterSave.setHealth(existingCharacter[2].getHealth());
    }
    else if (characterChoice == "4" || characterChoice == "Balrogg") {
        cCharacter[0] = existingCharacter[3]; cCharacterSave.setHealth(existingCharacter[3].getHealth());
    }
    else {
        cout << "Program Failure....Invaid Input!" << endl;
    }
    secondFighter();
    return;
}

void secondFighter() {
    string cFighter;

    cout << "***************" << endl;
    cout << "*   Fighter   *" << endl;
    cout << "***************" << endl;
    cout << "Choose Who To Fight!" << endl;

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i >= 0 && i <= 3; i++, j++) {
        cout << j << ": " << existingCharacter[i].getName();
        cout << "\t" << "Health: " << existingCharacter[i].getHealth();
        cout << "\t" << "Strength: " << existingCharacter[i].getAttack();
        cout << "\t" << "Speed: " << existingCharacter[i].getSpeed();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Enter Selection: ";
    if (purposeIgnore >= 1)
        cin.ignore();

    getline(cin, cFighter);
    changeCase(cFighter);

    if (cFighter == "1" || cFighter == "Shabu")
        cCharacter[1] = existingCharacter[0];
    else if (cFighter == "2" || cFighter == "Calil")
        cCharacter[1] = existingCharacter[1];
    else if (cFighter == "3" || cFighter == "Goltero")
        cCharacter[1] = existingCharacter[2];
    else if (cFighter == "4" || cFighter == "Balrogg")
        cCharacter[1] = existingCharacter[3];
    else { cout << "Invalid Input! Program Failure....Please Close and Restart" << endl; }

    return;
}

void fightScene() {
    int fight_choice;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 5;
    bool win;

    if (timesWon >= 1)
        j = 6;

    while (cCharacter[0].getHealth() > 0 && cCharacter[1].getHealth() > 0) {
        newlines();

        cout << "\t\t" << cCharacter[0].getName() << " choose ";

        if (i == 0)
            cout << "an attack.";

        else
            cout << "another attack.";

        do {
            cout << "\n\n\t\t<1. Punch / 2. Kick>\n\t\t<3. Slam / 4. Drop kick>";

            if (j == 6)
                cout << "\n\t\t<5. Items>";

            cout << endl << "\t\t";
            cin >> fight_choice;
        } while (fight_choice <= 0 || fight_choice >= j);

        if (fight_choice == 1) {
            cCharacter[1].setHealth(cCharacter[1].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[0].getAttack(), cCharacter[0].getSpeed(), 1));
            cout << "\n\t\tYou Punched " << cCharacter[1].getName() << ", his health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[1].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[1].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (fight_choice == 2) {
            cCharacter[1].setHealth(cCharacter[1].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[0].getAttack(), cCharacter[0].getSpeed(), 2));
            cout << "\n\t\tYou Kicked " << cCharacter[1].getName() << ", his health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[1].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[1].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (fight_choice == 3) {
            cCharacter[1].setHealth(cCharacter[1].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[0].getAttack(), cCharacter[0].getSpeed(), 3));
            cout << "\n\t\tYou Slamed " << cCharacter[1].getName() << " on the ground, his health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() <= 0)

            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[1].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[1].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (fight_choice == 4) {
            cCharacter[1].setHealth(cCharacter[1].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[0].getAttack(), cCharacter[0].getSpeed(), 4));
            cout << "\n\t\tYou Drop Kicked " << cCharacter[1].getName() << ", his health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[1].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[1].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (timesWon >= 1 && fight_choice == 5) { // Bars
            use_bar();
        }

        // Second fighter attack

        srand(time(NULL));
        int ran_pick = rand() % 5 + 1;

        if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() < 0) {
            ran_pick = 0;
            win = 1;
        }

        else if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() > 0) {
            cout << "\n\t\t<" << cCharacter[1].getName() << "'s turn>" << endl;
            win = 0;
        }

        if (ran_pick == 0)
            continue;

        else if (ran_pick == 1) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[1].getAttack(), cCharacter[1].getSpeed(), 1));
            cout << "\n\t\t" << cCharacter[1].getName() << " punched you! Your health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[0].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[0].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[0].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (ran_pick == 2) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[1].getAttack(), cCharacter[1].getSpeed(), 2));
            cout << "\n\t\t" << cCharacter[1].getName() << " kicked you! Your health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[0].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[0].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[0].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (ran_pick == 3) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[1].getAttack(), cCharacter[1].getSpeed(), 3));
            cout << "\n\t\t" << cCharacter[1].getName() << " slammed you on the ground! Your health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[0].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[0].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[0].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (ran_pick == 4) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() - fightMoves(cCharacter[1].getAttack(), cCharacter[1].getSpeed(), 4));
            cout << "\n\t\t" << cCharacter[1].getName() << " drop kicked you! Your health is now: ";

            if (cCharacter[0].getHealth() <= 0)
            {
                cout << "0" << endl << endl; cCharacter[0].setHealth(-1);
            }

            else
                cout << cCharacter[0].getHealth() << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (ran_pick == 5)
            cout << "\t\t" << cCharacter[1].getName() << " missed you! Your health is still: " << cCharacter[0].getHealth() << endl << endl;

        if (cCharacter[0].getHealth() > 0) {
            cout << "\n\t\t";
            system("PAUSE"); // Lets them read the attacks
        }

        i++; // Increases i to change some wording
    }

    if (win == 1)
        roundWon();

    else
        characterLost();

    return;
}

int fightMoves(int st, int sp, int num) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rand_num;
    int addition;

    switch (num) {
    case 1: {
        rand_num = rand() % 40 + 1;
        addition = (st + sp) / rand_num;
        cout << "\n\t\tDamage inflicted: " << addition;
        return addition; break;
    }
    case 2: {
        rand_num = rand() % 20 + 1;
        addition = (st + sp) / rand_num;
        cout << "\n\t\tDamage inflicted: " << addition;
        return addition; break;
    }
    case 3: {
        rand_num = rand() % 30 + 1;
        addition = (st + sp) / rand_num;
        cout << "\n\t\tDamage inflicted: " << addition;
        return addition; break;
    }
    case 4: {
        rand_num = rand() % 30 + 1;
        addition = (st + sp) / rand_num;
        cout << "\n\t\tDamage inflicted: " << addition;
        return addition; break;
    }
    }
}

int start()
{
    while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y') {
        fightScene();
        if (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')
            secondFighter();
    }
    return 0;
}

void roundWon() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    timesWon++;
    purposeIgnore++;
    cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacterSave.getHealth());
    cCharacter[1].setHealth(100);
    int item_won = rand() % 3 + 1;

    cout << "\t\tYou won!";
    cout << "\n\n\t\tYou have been rewarded ";

    if (item_won == 1) {
        cout << "a small protein bar! (+20 health)";
        bars.bar_small++;
    }

    else if (item_won == 2) {
        cout << "a medium protein bar! (+30 health)";
        bars.bar_medium++;
    }

    else if (item_won == 3) {
        cout << "a large protein bar! (+40 health)";
        bars.bar_large++;
    }

    cout << "\n\n\t\tItems can be used in game at the cost of a turn.";

    cout << "\n\n\t\t";
    system("PAUSE"); // Lets them read

    int ability_gain[3] = { rand() % 10 + 1, rand() % 10 + 1, rand() % 10 + 1 };

    cCharacter[0].setHealth(ability_gain[0] += cCharacter[0].getHealth());
    cCharacterSave.setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth());
    cCharacter[0].setAttack(ability_gain[1] += cCharacter[0].getAttack());
    cCharacter[0].setSpeed(ability_gain[2] += cCharacter[0].getSpeed());

    cout << "\n\t\tYour health is now: " << cCharacter[0].getHealth();
    cout << "\n\t\tYour strength is now: " << cCharacter[0].getAttack();
    cout << "\n\t\tYour speed is now: " << cCharacter[0].getSpeed();

    cout << "\n\n\t\tWould you like to fight another person? (y/n) ";
    cin >> repeat;

    return;
}

void characterLost() {
    cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacterSave.getHealth());
    cCharacter[1].setHealth(100);
    purposeIgnore++;

    cout << "\n\n\t\tYou have lost.";
    cout << "\n\t\tWould you like to fight another person? (y/n) ";
    cin >> repeat;

    return;
}

void use_bar() {
    int choose_bar;
    char another_bar;

    do {
        cout << "\n\n\t\tWhich bar would you like to use? ";
        cout << "\n\t\t 1: Small Bar: " << bars.bar_small;
        cout << "\n\t\t 2: Medium Bar: " << bars.bar_medium;
        cout << "\n\t\t 3: Large bar: " << bars.bar_large;

        do {
            cout << "\n\n\t\tI choose: ";
            cin >> choose_bar;
        } while (choose_bar <= 0 || choose_bar >= 4);

        if (choose_bar == 1 && bars.bar_small >= 1) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() + 20);
            bars.bar_small--;
            cout << "\n\n\t\tYour health is now: " << cCharacter[0].getHealth();
        }

        else if (choose_bar == 2 && bars.bar_medium >= 1) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() + 30);
            bars.bar_medium--;
            cout << "\n\n\t\tYour health is now: " << cCharacter[0].getHealth();
        }

        else if (choose_bar == 3 && bars.bar_large >= 1) {
            cCharacter[0].setHealth(cCharacter[0].getHealth() + 40);
            bars.bar_large--;
            cout << "\n\n\t\tYour health is now: " << cCharacter[0].getHealth();
        }

        else
            cout << "\n\t\tNot enough bars!";

        cout << "\n\n\t\tWould you like to use another bar? (y/n) ";
        cin >> another_bar;
    } while (another_bar == 'y' || another_bar == 'Y');

    return;
}

void newlines() {
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
}

void changeCase(string &convert) {
    for (int i = 0; convert[i]; i++) {
        if (isupper(convert[i]))
            convert[i] = tolower(convert[i]);
        else
            continue;
    }

    convert.at(0) = toupper(convert.at(0));

    return;
}

void bSmith()
{
    Blacksmith shopKeeper; //The shop keeper

    int responce; //Menu navigation
    cout << "*******************************" << endl;
    cout << "*  Welcome to the Blacksmith  *" << endl;
    cout << "*******************************" << "\n" << endl;

    cout << "*****************************" << endl;
    cout << "*     1: Purchase Items     *\n";
    cout << "*       2: Sell Items       *\n";
    cout << "*    3: List Your Items     *\n";
    cout << "*        4: Currency        *\n";
    cout << "*          5: Exit          *\n";
    cout << "*****************************" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Option Here: ";
        cin >> responce;

        switch (responce)
        {
        case 1:
            shopKeeper.buyItem(cCharacter[0]);
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            cout << "*       Items To Sell       *" << endl;
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            shopKeeper.sellItem(cCharacter[0]);
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            cout << "*    Character Inventory    *" << endl;
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            cCharacter[0].listInv();
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            cout << "*   Current Gold Currency   *" << endl;
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            cout << "\t" << cCharacter[0].getCurrency() << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            cout << "*    Thanks for shopping    *" << endl;
            cout << "*****************************" << endl;
            return;

        default:
            cout << "Please enter valid data." << "\n";
            break;
        }
        cout << "*****************************" << endl;
        cout << "*     1: Purchase Items     *\n";
        cout << "*       2: Sell Items       *\n";
        cout << "*    3: List Your Items     *\n";
        cout << "*        4: Currency        *\n";
        cout << "*          5: Exit          *\n";
        cout << "*****************************" << endl;
    } while (responce != 5);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you learned to use a debugger?  It's really one of the most useful tools a programmer can have.

Comment: ***The issue is "Run-Time Check Failure #3*** I believe you hit Retry when this box pops up. Then follow the callstack up to your code and Visual Studio will show you the problem. Also did you ignore a compiler warning?

Comment: What does it mean by "if (win == 1)X" Where the x is, it triggered a break point

Comment: @T.Godfrey *however, it clearly is set in the fightScene() function.* -- The running of your program disagrees with you.  So you're going to fight with the message, or admit something is wrong and you need to start debugging?  Also you could reduce a lot of the duplication of the code and the size of that `while` loop by using arrays of messages and just index into that array using the `fight_choice` value as an index.

Comment: It means that at the line selected the value of win was not set. Most likely the reason is the one given in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

All I can see that sets  `win` is this part of the code,

```
    if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() < 0) {
        ran_pick = 0;
        win = 1;
    }

    else if (cCharacter[1].getHealth() > 0) {
        cout << "\n\t\t<" << cCharacter[1].getName() << "'s turn>" << endl;
        win = 0;
    }
```

However, if `cCharacter[1].getHealth()==0`, `win` will be left unset.